# How to iterate over entire range /wo overflow of counter?

Tags: c++11

How to execute the body of the loop for every member of some type? I know I could repeat the body of the loop for the `maxval` after the loop, but it would be duplicating code which is bad. I also could make a function out of the body but it looks wrong to me too because functions should be small and simple and the body of the loop is huge.

```
const auto minval = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
const auto maxval = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
for (auto i = minval; i < maxval; ++i) {
    // huge body of the loop
}
```

Comment: not sure how "but it looks wrong to me too because functions should be small and simple and the body of the loop is huge" is an argument since all this code needs to be in a function one way or another. Anyway, you could also put it in a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as stopping after you process the last item:

```
auto i = minval;
while(1) {
    // do all the work for `i`


    if (i == maxval) break;
    ++i;
}
```

One can also move the increment to the top of the loop, provided it is skipped on the first pass:

```
i = minval;
switch (1) {
case 0:
    do {
        ++i;
case 1:
        // processing for `i`
    } while (i != maxval);
}
```

The latter version translates to efficient machine code a little more directly, as each loop iteration has only a single conditional branch, and there is a single unconditional branch, while in the first there is a conditional branch plus an unconditional branch which both repeat every iteration.

Neither version increments the ultimate value, which might be undefined behavior.

Comment: As I had to learn once, jumping into a loop as you do with `case 1:` can be contraproductive. Compilers are built to optimize *common* code, so doing something tricky like this easily confuses the compiler which leads to no compiler optimization at all. Due to this, the second code may actually run significantly *slower* than the first one. Truth is only in measurement, and it may be different for different compilers. Best avoid such premature optimization, and it is premature to throw such a ghastly construct at the code without proving it to be efficient first.

Comment: @cmaster: It may come as a surprise, but this case isn't that uncommon.  It's a simplification of Duff's Device, which appears quite often during loop unwinding (both automatic and by hand).  So I would expect the optimizer to handle it well (although it probably turns the first, simpler source code into the second automatically).

Comment: I know Duff's device, and I know that something quite similar killed all compiler optimization for me once. In assembler it would have worked like a charm but in C it was not achievable. I concluded to use Duff's device and similar tricks only as a very last resort, and only under strict control of measurement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain a bit of additional state to indicate whether you've seen the last value or not. Here's a simple example that could be moved to a more idiomatic iterator style without too much work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class allvalues
{
public:

    allvalues() = default;

    T next()
    {
        if (done) throw std::runtime_error("Attempt to go beyond end of range");
        T v = val;
        done = v == std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
        if (!done) ++val;
        return v;
    }

    bool isDone() { return done; }

private:

    T val = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    bool done = false;
};

int main() {

    allvalues<char> range;
    while (!range.isDone())
    {
        std::cout << "Value = " << (int)range.next() << std::endl;
    }

    allvalues<unsigned char> urange;
    while (!urange.isDone())
    {
        std::cout << "Value = " << (unsigned int)urange.next() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "That's it!" << std::endl;
}
```